# Subtracting values from a Pandas Dataframe in an Iterative Fashion

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like the one shown below. I am trying to subtract the value `1` in an iterative manner from the values in `column A` till the value in `column B` becomes 0. The order of subtraction would be decided by sorting using the columns `Sort1` and `Sort2` in an ascending manner such that 1 would be first subtracted from `column A` `row 3` and then 1 would be subtracted again from `column A` `row 4` and finally from `column A` `row 0`
I need to perform this operation for each group present in column B separately.

```
Inital DataFrame:

   A  B Sort1  Sort2
0  1  3     A    0.7
1  1  3     B    0.3
2  1  3     C    0.5
3  2  3     A    0.2
4  2  3     A    0.5
5  1  4     A    0.7
6  1  4     B    0.3
7  1  4     C    0.5
8  2  4     A    0.2
9  2  4     A    0.5


Result Dataframe:

   A  B Sort1  Sort2
0  0  0     A    0.7
1  1  0     B    0.3
2  1  0     C    0.5
3  1  0     A    0.2
4  1  0     A    0.5
5  0  0     A    0.7
6  0  0     B    0.3
7  1  0     C    0.5
8  1  0     A    0.2
9  1  0     A    0.5
```

I can achieve this by looping through the dataframe but the dataframe can be huge and wanted to explore if there is any better way to achieve this?

Comment: You don't talk about how column `B` values change or am I missing something?

Comment: Basically, since the value in column B is 3, I am subtracting 1 three times from column A in the iterative fashion I mentioned on the question. Hope that gives more clarity. @divingTobi

Comment: But you must be doing something to column `B` as well, because otherwise it would not change from 3 to 1 for all entries, no? Or are all the values in column `B` always the same, and this is basically the number of times you want to run the subtraction from `A`?

Comment: Yes. You are right. The values in column B will always be the same. It's basically to keep track of how many times the subtraction needs to happen or whether it needs to happen at all. So if it is 0 basically I don't need to do the subtraction anymore.

Comment: Isn't "iterative subtraction" the same as multiplying a subtracting number (say -1 in this instance) by the value in column B and subtracting that? So rather than -1, -1, -1, just do -3 that should be 3 times faster. If you want to stop subtracting when you get below zero, write it up as a floored subtraction function and apply that. e.g. `lambda x,y : 0 if x<y else x-y` having defined that function, you could apply it as a single call to the dataframe which would require no loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a shorter way to achieve the same, without requiring to loop through the groups:

```
import pandas as pd

# df_ = pd.read_clipboard()
df = df_.copy()

s = df.sort_values(by=['Sort1', 'Sort2']).groupby("B", group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.head(x.name))['A']-1

df.loc[s.index, "A"] = s

print(df)
```

which results in

```
   A  B Sort1  Sort2
0  0  3     A    0.7
1  1  3     B    0.3
2  1  3     C    0.5
3  1  3     A    0.2
4  1  3     A    0.5
5  0  4     A    0.7
6  0  4     B    0.3
7  1  4     C    0.5
8  1  4     A    0.2
9  1  4     A    0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is really what you are looking for. For every group (by column `B`) we select the first n elements (determined by the value in `B`), subtract 1 off column `A`, and then merge the results back to df.

```
import pandas as pd

# df = pd.read_clipboard()

print(df)

gp = df.groupby("B")

s = pd.DataFrame()

for k in gp.groups.keys():
    s = s.append(
        gp.get_group(k).sort_values(by=["Sort1", "Sort2"]).iloc[0:k][["A"]] - 1
    )

print(s)

df2 = df.merge(s, how="left", left_index=True, right_index=True)
ind = ~df2["A_y"].isna()
df2.loc[~df2["A_y"].isna(), "A_x"] = df2["A_y"]
df2 = df2.rename(columns={"A_x": "A"}).drop("A_y", axis=1)
```

It's a bit convoluted, but basically I am sorting the values as you describe, then select the first 3 columns (based on the value in `B`), and subtract one off of each.

The remainder is just to merge that new column back to the original dataframe:

```
     A  B Sort1  Sort2
0  0.0  3     A    0.7
1  1.0  3     B    0.3
2  1.0  3     C    0.5
3  1.0  3     A    0.2
4  1.0  3     A    0.5
5  0.0  4     A    0.7
6  0.0  4     B    0.3
7  1.0  4     C    0.5
8  1.0  4     A    0.2
9  1.0  4     A    0.5
```

I have not changed `B`, because I do not use it for iterating. You could just set it to `0` if you need to: `df2['B']=0`.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for the solution. I think I finally understood the confusion regarding column B now. Sorry about that. So, the problem is I could have different sets of values for column B in the same dataframe and I need to perform this operation separately for each of those groups in column B basically. I'll modify the question.

Comment: And for each set, the number in `B` represents the number of times, 1 should be subtracted?

Comment: Would you mind marking the question as answered? Thanks!